# Unhiding an Image Before Loading Large Scene

Tags: swift

I’m trying to unhide an image before presenting a scene that takes a few seconds to load. If I remove the presentScene the loadscreenman image displays correctly. Not sure why the loadscreenman is not appearing when the presentScene exists. It would be pure luxury to have that image appear while the scene loads.

```
if (node.name == “btnGameOnMan") {
    loadscreenman.hidden = false
    callgammescenefun()
}

func callgammescenefun()
{
    loadscreenman.hidden = false
    let reveal = SKTransition.doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration(0.2)
    let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
    self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: reveal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a `NSNotification` if `node.name == “btnGameOnMan"` like this:

```
if (node.name == “btnGameOnMan") {

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    loadscreenman.hidden = false
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationFired", object: nil)
     })
}
```

And then receive the fired notification in your `callgammescenefun()` like this:

```
func callgammescenefun(notification: NSNotification){
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.callgammescenefun(_:)), name: "NotificationFired", object: nil)
.
.   //your code
.

}
```

After this, write it outside the function:

```
deinit{
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
```

Comment: Anytime! Happy coding! :)